# Using PHP to get the current Wordpress ID into my DB

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, function

Creating my first plugin which allows people to create characters. This should work almost like online RPG games. The goal here is for a wordpress user to have multiple characters linked to that specific user. 
Take World of Warcraft for example: You create an account and then you can create several characters which you can remove or update.

I have two tables in a database i'm trying to put together.

The first table, wp_users has a Primary Key (ID) that I would like to use for a primary/foreign key relationship with my second table.

The second table, myth_char simply has two fields. A foreign key (ID) and a varchar called (char_name).

So if someone with a user_id of 5 created a couple characters, Thork, Mork, and Spork, I would like those characters to be connected to the user_id of 5. To make this work, I have used two different PHP files.

The first file contains a form where a user can insert a character name. **Here's the part i'm having trouble with. I'm using a built in wordpress function get_current_user_id, but it doesn't seem to be grabbing the user ID.** I've also made a variable that calls the function.

```
<?php
 //THIS FUNCTION GRABS CURRENT USER ID
 function get_current_user_id() {
    if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_get_current_user' ) )
        return 0;
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    return ( isset( $user->ID ) ? (int) $user->ID : 0 );
}
// CALL THIS FUNCTION NOW WHILE THE USER IS HERE AND LOGGED IN. THEN THE NEXT PHP PAGE WILL REQUIRE THIS FUNCTION AND INSERT IT INTO THE DB TABLE.
$wpid = get_current_user_id();
?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>CREATE YOUR CHARACTER</title>
        <link href="stylesheets/public.css" media="all"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <h1>CREATE YOUR CHARACTER HERE</h1>
        </div>
        <p>Please insert a name for your character.</p><br />

        <form action="form_processor.php" method="post">
            Character Name: <input type="text" name="charname" value"" /><br />
            <br />
            <input type ="submit" name ="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The second file has the connection to the DB and an insert query. It inserts the character name into the DB table myth_char_two, and it's SUPPOSE to insert the Wordpress user ID as well.

```
<?php

require_once('/home/mythlarp/public_html/wp-content/plugins/character_creation/form.php');

function redirect_to($new_location) {
    header("Location: " . $new_location);
}


//1. CONNECT TO DATABASE 
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "*****";
    $dbpass = "*****";
    $dbname = "*****";
    $connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

//2. GRAB INFORMATION FROM THE FORM IN "form.php" AND ALSO GRAB THE CURRENT WORDPRESS USER'S ID with the variable "$wpid".

// $charactername = if charactername is set to the form value then use the form value. Otherwise set it to nothing.

$charname = isset($_POST['charname']) ? $_POST['charname'] : "";
// This grabs the current Wordpress user ID from "form.php".


// 3.INSERT FORM VALUES INTO DB TABLE
$query  = "INSERT INTO myth_char_two (";
$query .= "charname id";
$query .= ") VALUES (";
$query .= " '{$charname}', {$wpid}";
$query .= ")";
//$result calls the $connection and $query.
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
// 4.TEST FOR QUERY ERROR.
if ($result) {
    redirect_to("character_finish.php");
} else {
    die("Database query failed.");
}

?>
```

This form is also on a separate page from any regular wordpress page. Right now it's just a regular php file without styling. That might be why it's not finding any ID. However I've tried to display it to myself on one of the regular theme pages and I've had no luck displaying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Change the form like this so that alone as per your db file it will grab the charname and wpid.

You no need to replicate the function into your page. You just call the function **get_current_user_id()**

**First File**(Change this)

**Remove:**

> Since this is already defined in Wordpress

```
 //THIS FUNCTION GRABS CURRENT USER ID
 function get_current_user_id() {
    if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_get_current_user' ) )
        return 0;
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    return ( isset( $user->ID ) ? (int) $user->ID : 0 );
}
```

> Change the form

```
<form action="form_processor.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $wpid; ?>" />            
Character Name: <input type="text" name="charname" value"" /><br />
<br />
<input type ="submit" name ="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

**Second DB file**(Add this line below your isset of $_POST['charname'])

```
$wpid = isset($_POST['user_id']) ? $_POST['user_id'] : "";
```

> Change the Insert Query

```
$query  = "INSERT INTO myth_char_two (";
$query .= "charname,id";
$query .= ") VALUES (";
$query .= " '{$charname}','{$wpid}'";
$query .= ")";
```

Hence this will insert the ID into the database.

Comment: Thanks Naresh! I'm using your changes now, but before I can connect to my DB I need to figure out where to require the Wordpress function get_current_user_id();

Comment: In WordPress you no need to add seperate config file.you can call the wp-config file itself in this page.

Comment: Wow, your changes worked and thank you so much!!!!! I also had to "require_once" to the user.php file in the wp-includes folder. This is where that "get_current_user_id" function is. Now the function works. I added a "charname" of Bob and the ID = 0, meaning it did not see my ID. Maybe I just have to call that function on an actual Wordpress page.